# ReferenceError: window is not defined in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mqtt, paho

```
var pahoMqtt = require("paho-mqtt");
let client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("serverIp", port, "/ws", "clientId" + Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000));
```

When i run this on node server, i'm getting the following error

```
stack: 
   [ 'ReferenceError: window is not defined',
     '    at LibraryFactory (/var/www/html/btrade/server2/node_modules/paho-mqtt/paho-mqtt.js:2411:4)',
     '    at ExportLibrary (/var/www/html/btrade/server2/node_modules/paho-mqtt/paho-mqtt.js:86:20)',
     '    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/btrade/server2/node_modules/paho-mqtt/paho-mqtt.js:97:3)',
     '    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)',
     '    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)',
     '    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/var/www/html/btrade/server2/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)',
     '    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)',
     '    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)',
     '    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)',
     '    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)',
     '    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)',
     '    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/btrade/server2/server/controllers/trade.controller.js:25:16)',
     '    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)',
     '    at loader (/var/www/html/btrade/server2/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)',
     '    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/var/www/html/btrade/server2/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)',
```

Can anyone pls help me to how to use Paho.MQTT in node js. thanx in advance.

Comment: It seems `paho-mqtt` browser based library so its giving error of `window`

Comment: You should use this directly on client side not on node side

Comment: Please check https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript/issues/81. Look like module build for browser.

Answer (score 0):

The Paho Javascript client is currently only supported in the browser.

There is work underway to update it so it can run in NodeJS but it is not currently complete.

For now you can use the [MQTT.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) library. This library can be used both in NodeJS and in the browser and supports native MQTT and MQTT over Websockets (when used in the browser on MQTT over Websockets can be used)

Comment: tnq hardillb. i already used MQTT.js by installing mqtt-npm. its connects the websocket. but in Paho-MQTT we have 'onMessageArrive' event, but it is not there in mqtt-npm module. how can i get this 'onMessageArrive' event in mqtt module. is there any alternative event for that in mqtt module?

Comment: MQTT.js is not a drop in replacement, it has a different API. Received messages are delivered to the `message` event e.g. `client.on('message',function(topic,msg, packet){...})` https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#event-message